# No muestra mi array [angular]

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Estoy haciendo un programa en javascript, usando angular, tengo que mostrar un array de libros introducidos en un json, para ello he creado el componente libros, y en me encargo de llamar a dichos datos mediante un export, para luego en su correspondiente html, depositarlos todos alli, sin embargo, a pesar de que tenga la estructura construida y no me de ningún error el programa, no me muestra ningún libro. Adjunto el codigo a continuación de las diferentes partes de mi programa, centrándome en aquellas que dan dicha funcionalidad, por lo que no colocare el json, dado a su extensión.

```
//parte del json | mock_libros.ts
import { Libro } from './libros';
 
export const LIBROS: Libro[] = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "titulo" : "El extranjero",
        "autor" : "Albert Camus",
        "descripcion" : "Camus retrata magistralmente la indolencia del hombre del siglo XX, un hombre que no encuentra su lugar, extranjero en su propio mundo. Este personaje escéptico y desapasionado que ha abandonado su condición de sujeto autónomo sigue siendo hoy un imprescindible referente literario y existencial."
    },

<!--Libros.component.html-->
<h2>LIBROS</h2>
<ul class="libros">
    <tr *ngFor="let libro of libros">
        <td>{{libro.id}}</td>
        <td>{{libro.titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{libro.autor}}</td>
    </tr>
</ul>
```

---

```
<!--Libros.component.ts-->
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LIBROS } from '../mock_libros';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-libros',
  templateUrl: './libros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./libros.component.css']
})
export class LibrosComponent implements OnInit{
  libros = LIBROS;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

```
<!--app.component.html-->
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
   {{ title }}
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
      <nav>
          <a routerLink="/libros" class="btn button bg-primary text-white">Ver libros</a>
          <a routerLink="/nuevo" class="btn button bg-primary text-white">Añadir nuevo</a>
      </nav>
  </div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

---

```
<!--app.module.ts-->
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LibrosComponent } from './libros/libros.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LibrosComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Puedes colocar una pequeña parte del `JSON`? Qué pasa si haces `console.log(libros)` en `ngInit`, se imprime un Objeto o un JSON String?

Comment: Buenas, ya lo añadi, y si hago un console log, me sale ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'libros'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'libros'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no mostras app-routing-module.ts Cambiaria "/libros" por "libros"
Prefiero definir en app-routing-module.ts las rutas de esta forma por el tema de Lazy Loading con el codigo te crea la ruta y hace un Update del modulo:

```js
 ng g m libros --route=libros -m app-routing.module.ts
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'libros', loadChildren: () => import('./libros/libros.module').then(m => m.LibrosModule) }];
```

tabla:

```js
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let libro of libros">
            <td>{{libro.id}}</td>
            <td>{{libro.titulo}}</td>
            <td>{{libro.autor}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Buena Teoria al respecto en:
[teoria rutas](https://academia-binaria.com/paginas-y-rutas-angular-spa/)

Comment: ¡Me ha funcionad, muchas gracias! :)

Comment: me alegra que te funcionara!